# How to run Apple UI Automaton script in terminal?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

```
instruments -w ‘AA6257B1-D3E0-49A6-85C2-F865B17ED6CD' \
-t '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate' \
'/Users/AZ-Admin/Downloads/test.app' \
-e UIASCRIPT '/Users/AZ-Admin/Desktop/UI\ Automation/ApTest.js' \
-e UIARESULTSPATH '/Users/AZ-Admin/Desktop/UI Automation'
```

Above is the instruction which I am giving to terminal for execution.
the problem I am facing here is my script is not executing only my Simulator is popping up and showing the app

I am also giving my ApTest.js code where my Automation Script is present

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
var testName = "Create a New Appointment";
UIALogger.logStart(testName);
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().elements()["Finder View"].buttons()["CRM"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["New Appointment"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Edit Table"].tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.56, y:0.21}});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to execute the script via Instruments GUI?

Also I'd try not to use UIARESULTSPATH, but output directly into console instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an error in your `-e UIASCRIPT '/Users/AZ-Admin/Desktop/UI\ Automation/ApTest.js' \` line.

Try using `-e UIASCRIPT "/Users/AZ-Admin/Desktop/UI/Automation/ApTest.js"` instead.

If it launches your app on the device you specify, you know the first two lines are correct. It sounds like Instruments doesn't know what test code to run once it launches the target app.